# How to format a currency field in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, jquery, formatting

I have a currency field in one of my SharePoint 2013 lists...How do I automatically format the field.

**Example:**

If the user enters **30000** it should automatically format to **30,000**
and if he enters **500000** it should format to **500,000**

So the number should format to American dollar currency.

Can this be done using j query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the column type to **Currency** while creating the column, then you will get the format you want without any coding.

Currency columns are auto-formatted.

Comment: But when I tried retrieving the field value using SPServices..it is not displaying..Actually I am trying to display it in a table

Comment: Are you getting an error while retrieving? or it is being retrieved as plain 30000?

Comment: it is retrieving as 30000.0000

Comment: var value = 1250.223; var num = '$' + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"); /

Comment: Its not working...am getting an error

Comment: what error? what code did you put?

Answer (score 1):

I had created and tested  by creating a **currency** type  field and  working as per you requirement 
[image]

[image]

Comment: But when I tried retrieving the field value using SPServices..it is not displaying..Actually I am trying to display it in a table